# Python Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

This feels like it should be obvious, but I'm missing the correct form.

Given a list of strings like

`fields = ["format = gatheringnutsinmay", "device = TESTX"]`

I am trying to write a dict comprehension to make a dictionary of the fields:

`items = {"format": "gatheringnutsinmay", "device": "TESTX }`

I've got at the moment:

```
_kv_seperator = re.compile(r"\s*=\s*")
items = {fk: fv for f in fields for [fk, fv] in _kv_seperator.split(f)}
```

but I get the error:

`_kv_seperator.split(f)`

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Corrections, please!

Comment: If you want to use a dict comprehension just use the split str method instead of regex: `{s.split(' = ')[0]: s.split(' = ')[1] for s in fields}`

Comment: Why doesn't the re split method work? It returns a correct list? `['format', 'gatheringnutsinmay'] `

Comment: I dont think your nested comprehension is doing what you think it is. It looks like you're trying to unpack strings into [fk, fv] and if the string is longer than 2 char it will return the error youre seeing. If you would like to use the re package you can do something like: `{k:v for k,v in [_kv_seperator.split(f) for f in fields]}`. 

Personally I would try to keep it simple and not introduce the re package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the second for loop, one way to see your dictionary comprehension is the following:

```
items = {}
for f in fields:
    for [fk, fv] in _kv_seperator.split(f):
        items[fk] = fv

print(items)
```

When you write:

```
for [fk, fv] in _kv_seperator.split(f)
```

You tell Python that you are expecting an iterable composed of 2-tuples, but actually

```
_kv_seperator.split(f)
```

only returns a single tuple, hence the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

You could do the following instead:

```
import re

fields = ["format = gatheringnutsinmay", "device = TESTX"]
_kv_seperator = re.compile(r"\s*=\s*")
items = {fk: fv for fk, fv in map(_kv_seperator.split, fields)}

print(items)
```

Or simply:

```
items = dict(map(_kv_seperator.split, fields))
print(items)
```

Or, if you prefer, you could do:

```
items = {fk: fv for fk, fv in (_kv_seperator.split(f) for f in fields)}
```

Comment: Didn't Guido say that using comprehensions we could get rid of map() and filter() ? :-) In practical terms your second option is the best, and preserves the regex expression - necessary because these strings sometimes come from end user edited files....

Comment: IMHO there some context where using map is clearer, one example is this one

Comment: I dont think this portion of the answer is correct: ```You tell Python that you are expecting an iterable composed of 2-tuples, but actually

_kv_seperator.split(f) 
only returns a single tuple, hence the error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```

I don't want to put too much mental effort into unpacking this nested comprehension, but you can quickly prove this to yourself by doing: `{l: l for f in fields for l in _kv_seperator.split(f)}` - you will see what is actually happening.

Comment: @lvrf What you put is not equivalent to what I wrote, `_kv_seperator.split(f)` does return a single tuple, but a tuple is an iterable in itself. Actually split returns a list, but for the purposes of my answer is equivalent

Comment: My point was that as far as I can tell it's perfectly legal to unpack the output of  `_kv_seperator.split` into `[fk, fv]`.

So for example: ```>>> fields = ["format = gatheringnutsinmay", "device = TESTX"]
>>> [k1,k2] = _kv_seperator.split(fields[0])
>>> k1, k2
('format', 'gatheringnutsinmay')```

Comment: Of course you can unpack them becauser they are a two elements, but you cannot do that in a loop

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed, I suggest use .split():

```
fields = ["format = gatheringnutsinmay", "device = TESTX"]
result = {}
for f in fields:
    f = f.split(" = ")
    result[f[0]] = f[1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a one liner is what you want, this'll do the trick:

```
items = {k:v for k,v in (sp.split(' = ') for sp in fields)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = { i.split('=')[0]:i.split('=')[1] for i in fields}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code bellow instead of using rex :

```
fields = ["format = gatheringnutsinmay", "device = TESTX"]
items = {f.split(" = ")[0]: f.split(" = ")[1] for f in fields}
items
```

Hope it helped.